# use images from assets folder instead of drawable folder in a ListFragment

Tags: java, android

im having a hard time to figure out how to use images from assets folders in the same way as in a drawable folder. i have searched and found that i can use getAssets() function, but i cant figure out how to use it, i have costume listview inside fragments. 
i dont want to use drawable folder because my assets contains some subfolders that i need.

[image]

this is what i have done so far, but the images are from drawable folder and i want to repace them with those in assets:

```
public class AfricaFragment extends ListFragment{

private AssetManager assets;

/** An array of items to display in ArrayList */
String android_versions[] = new String[]{
        "flag1",
        "flag2",
        "flag3",
        "flag4"
};
Integer[] imgid={ 
        R.drawable.a,
        R.drawable.b,
        R.drawable.c,
        R.drawable.d
};

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    assets = getActivity().getBaseContext().getAssets();
    InputStream stream;


    CustomListAdapter adapter=new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(), android_versions, imgid);
    this.setListAdapter(adapter);

    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    /** Setting the multiselect choice mode for the listview */
    getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

}
}
```

Im gratful for any help.

Comment: Use `AssetManager` and its `open()` method to get an `InputStream` on the asset. Then, pass that `InputStream` to `BitmapFactory.decodeStream()` to get a `Bitmap` of your image. It is also possible that some image-loading libraries (e.g., Glide, Picasso) can load from assets using the `file:///android_asset/` syntax that we normally use with `WebView`.

Comment: @CommonsWare: but how i can use it and store it as i did here for drawable: Integer[] imgid={ R.drawable.a, R.drawable.b, R.drawable.c, R.drawable.d };

Comment: That will be very complicated, as you will need to take into account how much memory you are using, background threading, and so on. If possible, I strongly encourage you to use an image-loading library as I suggested. Then, you would not cache the images yourself, but instead just ask the library for the image when it is needed. You will need to come up with some mapping between the data in your app and the relative paths to your images inside of `assets/`.

Comment: @CommonsWare: yes it seems that its very complicated. i will try to copie the images into drawable folder even if this is not convincing. thank you

Answer (score 1):

**To get image from assets :**

```
try {
        // Use image name with extension
        InputStream ims = getActivity().getAssets().open("flag1.jpg");
        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(ims, null);
        iv.setImageDrawable(d);
        ims .close();
    }
    catch(IOException ex) {
        return;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but how i can use it and store it as i did here for drawable: 
Integer[] imgid={ 
        R.drawable.a,
        R.drawable.b,
        R.drawable.c,
        R.drawable.d
};

Comment: You have already created a array for it android_versions that is fine for it, just add the extension(jpg/png) in the name like "flag1.jpg", "flag2.jpg",... then in your CustomListAdapter use the above code and get name with this array.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
    public Bitmap getBitmapFromAssets(String fileName) {
        AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();

        InputStream is = null;
        try{
            is = assetManager.open(fileName);
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

        return bitmap;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but how i can use it and store it as i did here for drawable: Integer[] imgid={ R.drawable.a, R.drawable.b, R.drawable.c, R.drawable.d };